# Context Menu Problem - how to resolve these menu items?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am very new to Android.

I am trying to build inflate a context menu within the sample GridView provided on the Android dev site. Eclipse tells me that the referenced items cannot be resolved, if someone could help find where I coded s.th. wrong, that would be great because I am stuck at the moment. Thanks.

I posted my entire code below. I get the error message at: `if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_facebook)` and the other R.id.'s

---

This is the ShareGalleryView.java file:

```
 import android.app.Activity; 
 import android.content.Context; 
 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.view.ContextMenu; 
 import android.view.MenuInflater; 
 import android.view.MenuItem; 
 import android.view.View; 
 import android.view.ViewGroup; 
 import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

 public class ShareGalleryView extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videogrid);

        GridView vGrid=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.vgrid);
        registerForContextMenu(vGrid);
        vGrid.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this));
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_gallery_share, menu);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_facebook)
        {
         //TODO open fb
            return true;

        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_youtube)
        {
            //TODO open youtube
            return true;

        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_email)
        {
         //TODO open email
            return true;

        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_bluetooth)
        {
            // TODO send via bluetooth
            return true;

        }
    }

    public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        // references to our images
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
                R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_2,
                R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_3,
                R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_1

        };
    }
}
```

and this is the menu_gallery_share.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_facebook"
          android:title="@string/Facebook" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_youtube"
          android:title="@string/YouTube" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_email"
          android:title="@string/Email" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_bluetooth"
          android:title="@string/Via Bluetooth" />
   </menu>
</menu>
```

Comment: the code you posted seems to be OK... can you show me the imports you are using at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Sure, just a second, I will post them.

Comment: Done!! Added them to the rest of the code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menu xml file is defined incorrectly. A `<menu>` can only have `<item>`s and `<group>`s. Remove the extra `<menu`> you have defined and it should work properly. Your project probably stopped building as well and you can check that in Eclipse's Android console. [See this documentation for more information about the menu resource.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Comment: I already found that, but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem :((

Comment: I just solved this problem I had to change the titles android:title="@string/Facebook" into android:title="Facebook", but it's still not running

Answer (score 0):

### PROBLEMS SOLVED!!

Wohooo, it works :) The first problem was within the xml file, here is the corrected code now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_facebook"
          android:title="Facebook" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_youtube"
          android:title="/YouTube" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_email"
          android:title="Email" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_bluetooth"
          android:title="Via Bluetooth" />
   </menu>
```

And for my second problem - **the unparsed aapt error** - I simply had to delete the error and clean the project :)

Thank you for the replies :)